# Gerenciar arquivos no servidor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, servidor, pdf, express.js

Estou fazendo um servidor usando NodeJS e Express e nele estou gerando pdfs de relatórios. Como faço para gerenciar esses arquivos, e quando falo em gerenciar me refiro à ter opções como abrir o pdf, baixá-lo e imprimir ele. Estou utilizando a biblioteca pdfMake porém ela está com bugs nessa parte de baixar, abrir ou imprimir o documento. E se possível pretendo continuar usando essa biblioteca para geração de pdfs por causa da sua facilidade de usar. Então, a minha dúvida é: **Tem como criar os métodos open(), print() e download() manualmente?? Se sim, como faço isso???**